# Uninstall Fragment when List becomes empty

Tags: android

Is there any callback/event that I can override when **List** becomes empty? Just like in `ListFragment`, when list becomes empty, it automatically shows **EmptyText(Empty Text Message)**. How it determines that list has become empty? I want because I want to remove `Fragment`.

I am working in Multi-pane layout.

Comment: Have you checked setOnHierarchyChangeListener()

Comment: i think by using size of list

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with simple solution

after removing item from **List**  always check `adapter.getCount()==0` is is true then your list is empty

Comment: Should I check it before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` or after it?

Comment: after before does't matter as you remove your element from `ArrayList` its become unavailable.`notifyDataSetChanged()` only request to update UI. So you can call before or after it will fine

Answer (score 0):

You can make a check everytime you add or remove item to the listView by using OnHieararchyChangeListerner

The parent will be the list view

```
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(new ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {
            if (((ListView) parent).getAdapter().getCount() == 0) {
                // Do what your want
            }
        }
    });
```